# How to Configure Jetty When the War is Deployed to a Nested Directory?

Tags: java, servlets, webserver, war, jetty-9

I have what I thought was a a simple task. Deploy a war into a jetty (v9.4) server and run the server. I packaged up the war and copied it into a nested folder in the $JETTY_BASE/webapps directory. I started up the server with the command `jetty -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar jetty.http.port=10202` . Everything seemed good, the server started up with no errors. However, when I try to navigate to what should be the index page in a browser, instead I get a page listing all the files in the directory. If I try to actually get to any of my services I get a 404 error.

The strange thing is, If I do the exact same thing but place the war directly under the webapps directory I can hit the index page just fine. I'm sure it's just a configuration option I missed somewhere by I have no idea which one. Does anyone know what I need to do to get this working?

For reference here is my jetty-web.xml for the application:

```
<Configure id="eyerep-data" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/eyerep-data</Set>
    <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.monitorDir" default="./webapps" />/eyerep-data.war</Set>    
</Configure>
```

The war is deployed to $JETTY_BASE/webapps/eyerep-data/eyerep-data.war

Answer (score 0):

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/jetty</Set>
    <Set name="war">absolute/path/to/jetty-app.war</Set>
</Configure>
```

http://localhost:8080/jetty.

ContextPath is important

**Works for me**

```
<Set name="monitoredDir">
    <SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="." />my/context
</Set>
```

Absolute path

```
<Set name="monitoredDir">/my/context</Set>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally figured it out. I needed to remove the leading '/' from my context path.